# How i make TouchableHightLight (checkbox) in React Native Accessibility?

Tags: react-native, touch, accessibility, react-native-ios

I work on accessibility for an ios app.

I use `TouchableHightLight` on checkboxes.

I need the screen reader of ios, the VoiceOver to know how to announced to the user if a checkbox has been checked or unchecked.

```
<View style={styles.rememberMeContainer}>
    <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="transparent"
        accessibilityLabel={props.rememberMeText}
        accessible={true}
        style={styles.rememberMeCheckBox}
        onPress={() => {props.setRememberMe(!props.rememberMe)}}>
        <Image style={styles.checkBoxImage}
               source={props.rememberMe ?
                    require("../../../images/general/v_icon_purple.png") : null}/>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <Text accessible={false} style={styles.rememberMeCheckBoxlabelStyle}>
        {props.rememberMeText}
    </Text>
</View>)
```

I read:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html
, but i don't find anything about it, or I missed something.

How can I do it accessible?

Answer (score 1):

```
    accessible={true}
    style={styles.rememberMeCheckBox}
    onPress={() => {props.setRememberMe(!props.rememberMe)}}>
    <Image style={styles.checkBoxImage}
           source={props.rememberMe ?
                require("../../../images/general/icon_unchecked.png") :  require("../../../images/general/icon_checked.png")}/>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (0.59), React Native doesn't support a `switch` or `checkbox` for `accessibilityRole`.

But there's a PR open adding support for it. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/24095

Hopefully, it will land in version 0.60.